# How to get intermediate point in Hermite-Simpson collocation method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, runge-kutta-methods

I'm reading J. Betts' book "Practical Methods for Optimal Control and Estimation Using Nonlinear Programming" and in the chapter on IVP there is Butcher tableau for Hermite-Simpson method:
$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
0           & 0            & 0           & 0             \\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{5}{24} & \frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{24} \\
1           & \frac{1}{6}  & \frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{6}   \\
\hline
         & \frac{1}{6}  & \frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{6}\end{array}
$$

General notation used is the following:
$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
\rho_1 & \alpha_{11} & \ldots & \alpha_{1K} \\
  \vdots & \vdots      &        & \vdots      \\
\rho_K & \alpha_{K1} & \ldots & \alpha_{KK} \\
\hline
         & \beta_1     & \ldots & \beta_k 
\end{array}
$$

Also there are formulas:
$$
\begin{align*}
&\mathbf{y}_{i+1} = \mathbf{y}_i + h_i\sum\limits_{j=1}^K \beta_j \mathbf{f}_{ij} \\
& \text{where } \mathbf{f}_{ij} = \mathbf{f}\left[\left(\mathbf{y}_i + h_i\sum\limits_{l=1}^K \alpha_{jl}\mathbf{f}_{il} \right), (t_i + h_i\rho_j)\right]
\end{align*}
$$

I don't understand how to get formula for intermediate point $\mathbf{y}_{i+1/2} = \frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{y}_i + \mathbf{y}_{i+1}) + \frac{h_i}{8}(\mathbf{f}_i - \mathbf{f}_{i+1})$ using these formulas above.

So I use the coefficients from the second row and get some ugly formula:
$$
\mathbf{y}_{i+1/2} = \mathbf{y}_{i} + h_i \left(\frac{5}{24}\mathbf{f}_{i1} + \frac{1}{3}\mathbf{f}_{i2} - \frac{1}{24}\mathbf{f}_{i3}\right)
$$
and I completely stuck, the only thing I managed to see is that $\mathbf{f}_{i1} = \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{y}_i, t_i) = \mathbf{f}_i$. But it doesn't help much. I need help because I'm confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a little different notation, let's rewrite it in the following form:
\begin{align}
\mathbf{y}_{i+1/2} &= \mathbf{y}_{i} + h_i\left(\frac{5}{24}\mathbf{f}_{i} + 
\frac{1}{3}\mathbf{f}_{i+1/2} - \frac{1}{24}\mathbf{f}_{i+1}\right) \\
&= \mathbf{y}_{i} + \frac{h_i}{2}\left(\frac{5}{12}\mathbf{f}_{i} + \frac{2}{3}\mathbf{f}_{i+1/2} - \frac{1}{12}\mathbf{f}_{i+1}\right)
\end{align}

Let's now notice that $\frac{5}{12}\mathbf{f}_{i} = \frac{1}{6}\mathbf{f}_{i} + \frac{1}{4}\mathbf{f}_{i}$ and $-\frac{1}{12}\mathbf{f}_{i+1}=\frac{1}{6}\mathbf{f}_{i+1} - \frac{1}{4}\mathbf{f}_{i+1}$. So we get:
$$
\mathbf{y}_{i+1/2} = \mathbf{y}_{i} + \frac{h_i}{2}\left(\frac{1}{6}\mathbf{f}_{i} + \frac{2}{3}\mathbf{f}_{i+1/2} + \frac{1}{6}\mathbf{f}_{i+1}\right) + \frac{h_i}{8}\left(\mathbf{f}_i + \mathbf{f}_{i+1}\right)
$$

Now let's notice that:
$$
\mathbf{y}_{i+1/2} = \frac{\mathbf{y_i}}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\left(\underbrace{\mathbf{y}_i + h_i\left(\frac{1}{6}\mathbf{f}_{i} + \frac{2}{3}\mathbf{f}_{i+1/2} + \frac{1}{6}\mathbf{f}_{i+1}\right)}_{\mathbf{y}_{i+1}}\right) + \frac{h_i}{8}\left(\mathbf{f}_i + \mathbf{f}_{i+1}\right)
$$

And finaly
$$
\mathbf{y}_{i+1/2} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\mathbf{y}_{i} + \mathbf{y}_{i+1}\right) + \frac{h_i}{8}\left(\mathbf{f}_i + \mathbf{f}_{i+1}\right)
$$